# How to do a durable post call in an ServiceBusTrigger azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Hey I'm using a `ServiceBusTrigger` azure function to get the messages received in a queue, and then send them to my webapi which is going to do some stuff with that content

```
[FunctionName("MyAzureFunction")]
public async void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("<MyQueue>", Connection = "<MyConnectionString>")] Message myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem.ToString()}");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    // Retrieving the string content from the message
    var bodyMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myQueueItem.Body);
    // Calling my API to do something based on the message content
    var response = await client.PostAsync("<MyAPIUrl>", new StringContent(bodyMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    // doing something based on the response
}
```

I've been reading about azure functions and in order to it gets cheaper I read about durable functions, I'm looking forward how to use them so I can take decisions based on my response and I can get it working with this `ServiceBusTrigger`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needs to be changed the current `ServiceBusTrigger` function so it calls another Function that will actually do the job:

```
[FunctionName("MyAzureFunction")] public async void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("<MyQueue>", Connection = "<MyConnectionString>")] Message myQueueItem,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient orchestratorClient,
    ILogger log) {

    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem.ToString()}");

    // Here is where you need to specify in the first parameter the name of the function to be called
    // and the last parameter are the params you'll send to that one
    var instanceId = await orchestratorClient.StartNewAsync("MyPostFunction", null, myQueueItem);

    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function created an async instance of 'MyPostFunction' with the ID: {instanceId}");
}
```

Then is needed to create another function that will be `OrchestrationTrigger` type, that will look like this:

```
[FunctionName("MyPostFunction")] public async void RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context) {
    // using the context can be retrieved the parammeters passed in the function above
    // in this case I just specify the type of that one and that's it
    var myQueueItem = context.GetInput<Message>();
    var bodyMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myQueueItem.Body);

    // Create a URI of your API url
    var postUri = new Uri($"<MyAPIUrl>");

    // depending on your WebAPI you'll need to specify the content type in the headers
    var headers = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>() { { "Content-Type", "application/json" } };
    // creating durable http request
    var request = new DurableHttpRequest(HttpMethod.Post, postUri, headers, bodyMessage);

    // Doing the http call async, in this context you'll save money since your function will not be completely waiting for a response
    // this one will keep just checking to see if there's a response available or not
    var response = await context.CallHttpAsync(request);

    // do your stuffs depending in the response
}
```

In my case I had to specicify the headers in the request, otherwise I used to get `415 Unsupported Media Type` can be done in that way, or just creating the request without specifying any header at the begining and then adding those like this:

```
var request = new DurableHttpRequest(HttpMethod.Post, postUri, null, bodyMessage);
request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Both options work